# Laravelのphp artisanコマンドをどこからでも実行できるようにするには？

Tags: laravel

Laravelのphp artisanコマンドはルートからでないと実行できないのでしょうか？
他の場所から実行できるようにするやり方はあるでしょうか？
ルートでない場所でphp artisanを実行したとき

> Could not open input file: artisan

とエラーが出力されてしまいます

Comment: ちなみになぜLatravelルート以外で実行する必要があるのでしょうか？単純に考えてしまえばルートディレクトリに移動して実行するではだめなのでしょうか？

Comment: 単純にどこからでも実行できたら便利だと思っただけです。たとえばControllerディレクトリでファイル操作してる最中にphp artisanで新しいコントローラーを作るとなったとき、一度ルートに移動してからまたControllerディレクトリに行ったり来たりすることがあるので、そう思いました。